# I am getting internal server error via ajax to controller for pusing a file via form to controller

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am passing excel file to controller  via ajax as data form,it throwing internal server error

```
function Python_Batch_Trigger() {

    var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
    formdata.append("username", "Test");
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
       contentType: false, 
        processData: false, 
        data: formdata,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            //$('.loader').show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
```

Comment: What does error message say?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, make sure you have added enctype attribute in form tag like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return ChecKFileName(event)" , id="form"}))
```

If this doesnot solve your issue.

Try writing you action and reading file like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public string Index()
{
   var file = Request.Files[i];
// Do your logic here.
}
```

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Index",
                                    "Home",
                                    FormMethod.Post,
                                    new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return ChecKFileName(event)" , id="form"}))
    {